# Apache works but the page does not load

Tags: php, apache

I have installed on my PC: Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.4.0, MySQL 5.5.
So I did not get any mistakes from Apache or PHP but, when I'm trying to load my local projects something wrong. Sometimes projects run, but sometimes Web page is not available.
Sometimes localhost working other not working. I don't know how to solve this problem, I didn't get mistake on my logs/error.
So anybody know what is this? I can put here any information if need.

This what logs show me.

```
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:02.765532 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00428: Parent: child process 5960 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:02.877538 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:02.877538 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Mar 17 2014 12:11:31
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:02.877538 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\server\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/server/Apache24'
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:02.879538 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5964
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:03.332564 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5964:tid 524] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:03.556577 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00428: Parent: child process 5964 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:03.695585 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:03.695585 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Mar 17 2014 12:11:31
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:03.695585 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\server\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/server/Apache24'
[Wed Apr 30 11:12:03.696585 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3748:tid 584] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1808 [Wed Apr 30**strong text**
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using ? You don't see if apache restart in logs ?

Comment: I use Windows 7 service pack 1 64 bit. Before, with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2 I didn't have problems. But when i update all this, now I have problems.

Comment: Does a `phpinfo()` file work?

Comment: The log is only the global log. What says the error log?

Comment: What's the page you are trying to execute ? No loops which induce a memory leaks ? I guess that, if you change your configuration of the project you omit to change the memory_limit.

Comment: I found. When i was trying to load page Apache restarting all the time. It was because i enable extra library in php.ini but didn't have this librarys on my ext folder. So Apache don't see extensionsions and that's why restarting. I comment extra extensions on my php.ini.
Now everything okey)))

Comment: In my case, it was just the versioning issue. Make sure to set an environment variable is same as that the version you are using in wamp server.